# Размытое изображение на 2 мониторе

Tags: nvidia, монитор

У меня размытая картинка на 2 мониторе. Использую GeForce GTX 760. Настройки по умолчанию. Основной монитор имеет разрешение 1920х1080, а 2 монитор 1280х1024(Сделать совместимо обе не могу т.к. основной 16х9 а 2 монитор 5х4)